# Is the announcement of an earnings conference call a good or bad sign?

Tags: quarterly-report

If a company announces that it plans to host a conference call after the quarterly fiscal report is released, is that predictive of the relative success of that quarter? Is it more likely to be celebratory or could it be preparing to soften the blow? Or are conference calls so commonplace that it is not necessarily an indicator either way?

For example: [MedReleaf Corp. to Host Third Quarter Fiscal 2018 Conference Call](http://markets.businessinsider.com/news/stocks/MedReleaf-Corp-to-Host-Third-Quarter-Fiscal-2018-Conference-Call-1014441794)

Comment: They are so commonplace they mean nothing. They are usually very bland reiterations of the 10K. The chance to hear other analysts talk to the executives and to yourself ask questions can be fun and informative though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's very common and I doubt it holds any predictive power:

> Results from the 2014 Earnings Call Practices Survey conducted by the National Investor Relations Institute (NIRI), a professional association of corporate officers and investor relations consultants, confirm that an overwhelming majority of public companies hold quarterly earnings calls—97 percent of the companies that responded to the survey report holding such calls.
>
> [...]
>
> Applicable rules, including Regulation FD and the safe harbor in Item 2.02(b) of Form 8-K for oral disclosures made during an earnings call, require companies to provide advance notice of earnings calls.  Companies share approaches when it comes to making these earnings call announcements: press releases and posts on company websites are the most common methods (93 percent and 83 percent, respectively).

https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=bc801101-b83d-4934-bd0f-71c01c0d3a04

Answer (score 4):

Most established companies hold a conference call and the existence of such has no predictive value whatsoever.  For a list of upcoming conference calls, Google: "earnings conference call calendar".  You'll find lots of web sites listing them.